# How to sync the modification date of folders within two directories that are the same?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a Dropbox folder on one computer with all the original modification dates. Recently, after transferring my data onto another computer, due to a .DS_Store issue, some of the folder's "Date Modified" dates were changed to today. I am trying to write a script that would take the original modification date of a folder, and then be able to find the corresponding folder in my new computer, and change it using `touch`. The idea is to use `stat` and `touch -mt` to do this. Does anyone have any suggestions or better thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: just `rsync` the folders, no?

Comment: Would the `rsync` command be able to only sync the modification date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use one folder as the reference for another with `--reference=SOURCE`:

```
$ cd "$(mktemp --directory)"
$ touch -m -t 200112311259 ./first
$ touch -m -t 200201010000 ./second
$ ls -l | sed "s/${USER}/user/g"
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Dec 31  2001 first
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Jan  1  2002 second
$ touch -m --reference=./first ./second
$ ls -l | sed "s/${USER}/user/g"
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Dec 31  2001 first
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Dec 31  2001 second
```